# curses dialog - Read output for checklist

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dialog, curses

I am making an installer for a program, using `dialog` (using curses) on `bash`. I made a `checklist` with a list of available packages. I tried to pipe the output to `grep` to identify the selected packages, and install them. However, after I exited the `dialog`, it messed up the command-line. I couldn't see what I was typing, and every new line was shifted over by what seemed like 10 chars or smth.
Here's an example that is similar to what I did:

```
dialog --backtitle "Installer" --title "Packages" --checklist "Choose packages to install:" 90 30 30 \
1 "Option 1" on \
2 "Option 2" on \
3 "option 3" off \
| grep

clear
```

Comment: `dialog` will print out the item numbers that are selected, separated by spaces. So with the defaults in that example, `1 2`. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish by using grep...

Comment: @Shawn I thought `dialog` outputted the checklist options as strings...

Comment: You didn't try running just the dialog part by itself? (Note: `--checklist` writes results to standard error, not standard output)

Comment: But still, how do I extract (so to speak) that info from the `stderr`? The `read` command only reads `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

A `dialog` checklist will, as the default, write the selected tags to standard error, separated by spaces. As long as you stick with single-word tags like the numbers in your example, one approach to reading them for later use is to use a command substitution that first redirects standard error to standard output, and then change standard output to `/dev/tty` so that `dialog` still works properly (See [Bash FAQ 040](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/040) for details), and store the tags in an array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a choices=( $(dialog \
                --backtitle "Installer" \
                --title "Packages" \
                --checklist "Choose packages to install:" 90 30 30 \
                1 "Option 1" on \
                2 "Option 2" on \
                3 "option 3" off 2>&1 >/dev/tty) )

for sel in "${choices[@]}"; do
    case "$sel" in
        1) echo "Option 1 selected.";;
        2) echo "Option 2 selected";;
        3) echo "Option 3 selected";;
        *) echo "Unknown option!";;
    esac
done
```

You can also make it write one tag per line with the `--separate-output` option, which can be easier to work with if your tags include spaces or if you're targeting `sh` instead of `bash` and thus don't have arrays.

---

A variation that builds the checklist dynamically from an array of options (Since you said you have a lot):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3")

declare -a cmd=(dialog --backtitle Installer --title Packages --no-tags
                --checklist "Choose packages to install" 90 30 30)

for opt in "${!options[@]}"; do
    cmd+=( "$opt" "${options[$opt]}" off )
done

declare -a choices=( $("${cmd[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty) )

for sel in "${choices[@]}"; do
    printf "Tag %d value %s selected\n" "$sel" "${options[$sel]}"
done
```

Comment: I don't want to echo the options, bc I have like 40 of em on my script. I want to do it silently.

Comment: @DepthsDoes Do whatever you need to. Just echoing them for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Also, what if I have multiple packages selected? How will I carry that out?

Comment: New version that doesn't need a temporary file -- and that's what the loop over the returned tags is for.

Comment: I didn't ask for that, I asked how I could carry out having multiple selected packages.

Comment: You mean in `dialog`? Space bar selects/deselects an option.

Comment: I meant, how will I be able to carry out commands for multiple options? cuz `case` / `esac` only works with one option at a time...